# Shell script- How to get 50 from the sting "T=50"?

Tags: string, bash, shell, parsing

I need to get the tail count from flat file. 
The tail row will look like below:

```
"TC=10"
```

I have used:

```
cnt=${trcnt#*=}
cnt=${cnt%%,*}
```

but I am getting cnt = "10".

Please tell the right command to get the count 10.

I need to extract 10 from "TC=10"

Comment: For this very particular exampe a simple grep could do the job: `grep -o '[0-9]*'`

Comment: @oguzismail : your self deleted answer looks right to me.

Comment: your subject headline differs from the actual problem description (not that it really matters, but ... why sow confusion? ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk`, and its `-F` option to define a "field separator":

```
| awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F'"' '{print $1}'
```

which is easier to understand than other alternatives, and very customizable. 
It's useful for two similar entries:

```
echo "TC=10" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F'"' '{print $1}'
echo "\"TC=10\"" | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F'"' '{print $1}'
```

Another option, related to what @shellter wrote:

> @oguzismail : your self deleted answer looks right to me.

that answer was:

```
    $ trcnt='"TC=10"'
    $ cnt=${trcnt#*=} # remove everything till first =
    $ cnt=${cnt%\"}   # remove trailing "
    $ echo "$cnt"
    10
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a better practice to match the number over removing what is not the number:

```
echo $trcnt | gawk '{match($0, /[0-9]+/); print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)}'
```

or
[How to extract a number from a string using Bash example](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-extract-a-number-from-a-string-using-bash-example)